# HTML and CSS how to hide text after background image is added to the section

Tags: html, css, background-image

Could someone please tell me how to hide the text "JN" 
after the background image is added to the same block?

HTML code

```
<body>
    <header>
        <h1 class="logo">JN</h1>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#youtube">YouTube</a></li>
                <li><a href="#articles">Articles</a></li>
                <li><a href="#vine">Vine</a></li>
                <li><a href="#social">Social</a></li>
                <li><a href="#podcasts">Podcasts</a></li>
                <li><a href="#share">Share</a></li>
                <li><a href="#more">More</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <a href="mailto:thisemailisforrandomstuffs@gmail.com">Email me</a>
    </header>
</body>
```

CSS code

```
h1.logo {

    background-image: url(JN-website-logo-Transparent-background.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

Comment: Well there are a lot of ways to make the text disappear, many I had place as I was growing up as developer. But let me tell you almost every one of them will cost the site heavily on the SEO front since Google crawlers will flag and will loose SEO visibility. Even solution where you change the color of the text to match the background image is consider as an usability offence, assuming you are trying to misguide the user. Please check my answer for the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `text-indent -9999px;`.
That shifts the text 9999px to the left out of the scope of the website.

Wouldn't it be easier just to delete the text?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using the image as background image, use it `img` tag. Here is an example:

```
<h1>
    <img src="path/to/logo.ext" alt="JN" title="JN" />
<h1>
```

Here is an additional example with links:

```
<h1>
    <a href="/">
        <img src="path/to/logo.ext" alt="JN" title="JN" />
    </a>
<h1>
```

**COMMENT FROM ABOVE**:

> Well there are a lot of ways to make the text disappear, many I had
>   place as I was growing up as developer. But let me tell you almost
>   every one of them will cost the site heavily on the SEO front since
>   Google crawlers will flag and will loose SEO visibility. Even solution
>   where you change the color of the text to match the background image
>   is consider as an usability offence, assuming you are trying to
>   misguide the user.